# Fixing internal email function with WHM on a dedicated server

Tags: email, cpanel, whm

I have a server by the name `svr1.domain.com` which runs on a CentOS with WHM. I have configured its email service to pass through a relay while discarding any email generating through the server name (e.g.: an account named **acc1** using cPanel has a wordpress which has a contact form. The contact form uses hosting's internal mail function upon some anon user submitting a query. Then the mail generates on cPanel as `acc1@svr1.domain.com`). Which means any mail generates as `account_name@svr1.domain.com` will be discarded.

Now, the question is; is there another way to over-come this issue so that these mails can by-passed or in-fact use some kind of SMTP mechanism to each cPanel account created through WHM?